How does one configure nginx for whitelabel solution?
I am trying to implement a whitelabel solution for my clients where they use their own domain or subdomain that is pointed to my server IP to serve my application.
For example:
subdomain.anydomain.com should always resolve to my server as long as it points to my server.
This is what I have done so far.
I have already created wildcard subdomains and it works good so far if I explicitly configure nginx to resolve that domain that is. For instance:
This works:
server_name *.mojahidul-islam.com *.imjol.com;
But This doesn't:
server_name _; #or server_name ~^.+$;
It gives me 502 Bad Gateway page and this is the error log:
2024/05/21 04:14:27 [error] 1415183#1415183: *1 no resolver defined to test.mojahidul-islam.com,
client: 45.248.151.42, server: ~^(?<subdomain>.+)\.(?<domain>.+)\.com$,
request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", host: "test.mojahidul-islam.com"

Here is my nginx config:
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name *.mojahidul-islam.com *.imjol.com; #This works
        #server_name _;# This does not work
        #server_name ~^.+$; This does not work as well

        resolver 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4;
        root /var/www/mojahid;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
        }


        # Pass PHP scripts to FastCGI server
        location ~ \.php$ {
                include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                include fastcgi_params;
        }

        # Deny access to .htaccess files
        location ~ /\.ht {
                deny all;
        }

}


PHP-FPM, NGINX are running properly fine. I am stuck at this point. Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks

There's nothing in your posted config that requires the usage of a resolver anyway, so you can omit that. - You need to ensure that you either only have a single server or that the server block that handles your "white label hosting" is the "default server".

Ok I did some more digging and got it working by adding another server block that proxy pases (I don't know the exact term) the request to one of my wildcard subdomain like proxy_pass "https://main.imjol.com";
But it only works for http protocol.
If I try https it redirects me to another server that resolves https requests.
